# How to Get UserID from Custom Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i would like to be able to get the ID of the Current user logged in on my Site.

The thing is that i'm not trying to get the Guid, but The User_ID, that is a field that i have on a custom table of mine called Users. On that table i have User_ID that is the PK and UserId that is a FK from the table aspnet_Users.

The reason i want this field is because i have a table Purchase that every time an User LOGGED IN presses the button saying (Buy), a new saleId is incremented and the User_ID that bought it. On my table Users the User_ID is of int type that starts at 1 and also increments every time a newUser registers on the site.

So it's easier to check an user by ID of (1,2,3) that an unique Identifier with 30 characters

**What i have in mind is something like this:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    string InsertSql = "INSERT INTO [Purchase] (User_ID) VALUES (@User_ID)";

            using (Connection)
            {

                Connection.Open();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(InsertSql, Connection);

                com.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@User_ID",  ????);

                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close(); 

             }
}
```

Where is ???? i need to get somehow the User_ID of the current User logged in that is on my custom table Users.

Thanks for the help

Comment: i think so, what do you mean by that exactly

Comment: dear check my second logic by using `ProviderUserKey`..

Answer (score 1):

After Log-in into your application you should maintain the userid into session variable ..so that later on you can use that directly.

Example:-

```
    //while user logged-in,push userid into session variable:-

    Session["userid"] = 12;

    //And later on in oyur page you can use it like :-

   com.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@User_ID",  (int)Session["userid"]);
```

Comment: How do i do "while user logged-in" and also, does each user have a different session?

Comment: yes ..each user will have different session..and you can do when user fills his username and password and clicks on login button then first you authenticate the user ..if user is valid then push the userid into session as i have shown above

Answer (score 0):

Assuming as you say that using is logged in

Use `User.Identity.Name`.

You check if user is authenticated using:

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

If will give you the name of the current logged user in your asp.net application.

```
com.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@User_ID",  User.Identity.Name);
```

Comment: yeah but when i do that it says that "Conversion" failed when converting the nvarchar value 'UserName' to data type in, Because the User_ID is of type int and basacly i'm adding a String, in this case the name of the username

Comment: Then you should query the database, make a select statement to recover the USER_ID having the username Maybe?

Comment: Hum... how do i do that exactly, i'm not very good at Sql commands

Comment: I dont really know your database fields but it should be something like: SELECT USER_ID FROM [USERS]  WHERE USER_NAME= @User_name

Comment: sorry for the delay, but where do run that query? And how do i integrate that query with the sqlInsert command that i have? Bacause when i do com.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@User_ID",  ????); i am using the command InsertSql

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Membership` then

Gets the name if authenticated.

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    Label1.Text = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
else
    Label1.Text = "No user identity available.";
```

If you want to get `userid` then run a `select` query like

```
Select userid from tablename where username = 'pass here username';
```

by running this query you will get `userid` and use that `userid` when you need.

Parametrized Query:

```
com.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@User_ID",  HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

and if you are not using `Membership` then at the time of `login` get `userid` from your `username` and use any where you want to.

Note: Make  sure that you have unique `username` otherwise it will give you multiple `userid`.

Logic 2:
Use the `ProviderUserKey` member of the `MembershipUser` object, like this:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
string userid = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
```

Hope it works..

Comment: The thing is that User_ID is of type int, and HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is the name of the Username, So therefore a string

Comment: if you have username then why u need userid,You can also apply query logic based on `username`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but i tried to do that already, the thing is that User_ID is of type int ant the providerskey if i'm not mistaken is a uniqueIdentifier so i get the error Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'd4ff64d6-1b6a-4e50-a59b-aea2c544ec1a' to data type int

Comment: do one thing after getting a username run an extra select query,,see my answer again i m gonna update it..

Comment: one last question. Where do i run the Select Query. Do i need to do a sqlCommand do run it? and do i call that query so i can use it on com.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@User_ID",  ????); I'm confused

Comment: you need to use sqlcommand to run it and then use the getting `userid` from that query in `com.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@User_ID", UserID);` here i put `UserID` instead of `????` because i m storing my `userid` that i have get from `select` query in 'UserID int variable`...ok

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you have a custom table `Users`, with PK `User_ID` and a column `UserId` that is a FK to the table aspnet_Users.

You already know the UserName of the logged in user, so why not simply do something like:

```
string InsertSql = @"
    INSERT INTO [Purchase] (User_ID)
    SELECT U.User_ID FROM Users U
    INNER JOIN aspnet_Users AU ON U.UserId = AU.UserId
    WHERE AU.LoweredUserName = LCASE(@UserName)
     ";
```

Your `@UserName` parameter is then the name of the current logged on user that you already know (`HttpContext.Current.User.Name`), and you don't need to know the User_ID.

Comment: I got this error Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'User_ID'

Comment: @user2394203 - then you need to debug the SQL statement.  E.g. is there a row in the Users table with a NULL value for User_ID?

Comment: Then debug it!  E.g. run that SELECT statement with the correct UserName in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

i finally did it, i kinda moved on to other stuff that i needed to do on my Site, so i just figured it out today.

I just wanna say thanks for all the replies and leave the solution to my own problem. Basically what i was doing wrong was the Select command. I'm not very good at SQL, so i didn't know were to place it xD, but now i know.

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

```
    MembershipUser usr =  Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
    Guid usrid = (Guid)usr.ProviderUserKey;

    String product= DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

    string InsertSql= "INSERT INTO [Purchase] (Product_ID, User_ID) VALUES (@Product_ID,(SELECT User_ID from [Users] where UserId = @UserId))";


        using (Connection)
        {
            Connection.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(InsertSql, Connection);

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_ID", product);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", usrid);

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Connection.Close();

        }

    Response.Redirect("Purchase.aspx");
}
```

Once again, thanks for all the patience and help
Take Care